# "Трёх часов" или "троих часов"?

Tags: количественно-именное-сочетание, собирательные-числительные

> ...всё имущество местных иезуитов состояло из простейшей мебели, нескольких подушек, подсвечников и **трёх часов**.

Понятно, что в этой фразе означает **"трёх часов"**, но выглядит и звучит это словосочетание в данном контексте не очень хорошо. Как улучшить концовку фразы?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Возможно, Вам, Матвей, следует использовать собирательное числительное "трое".
§ 165. Употребление собирательных числительных
І. Собирательные числительные двое, трое, четверо (остальные ... При слове часы (прибор) употребляется собирательное числительное (одни часы, двое часов) ...

Тогда фраза будет звучать следующим образом: "..всё имущество местных иезуитов состояло из простейшей мебели, нескольких подушек, подсвечников и троих часов".
(Хотя, если честно, мне такой вариант не очень нравится. Может быть, есть смысл перенести злополучные "часы"  и начать с них ряд  однородных дополнений?)

Comment: Спасибо, user183861!

Answer (score 1):

Корректно: всё имущество местных иезуитов состояло из простейшей мебели, нескольких подушек, подсвечников и **троих** часов.

> Собирательные числительные двое, трое, четверо... употребляются
>   с существительными, имеющими формы только множественного числа: двое саней, трое ножниц, четверо суток. [(§ 165. Употребление собирательных числительных](http://knigi.link/grafika-orfografiya-fonetika/165-upotreblenie-sobiratelnyih-22371.html))
>
> Говорим мы и «двое часов», «двое брюк». [Л. В. Успенский. Слово о словах (1971)]